# Spring ACL with properties file

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-security, acl

I would like to know if someone have tried to implement a spring acl feature, but instead of using a Database, use a simple properties file. for example :

myobject.input.field1=ACL_READ
myobject.input.field2=ACL_READ,ACL_WRITE

and in the jsp :

```xml
<sec:accesscontrollist hasPermission="ACL_READ" domainObject="myobject.input.field1">
This will be shown if the user has either of the permissions 
represented by the values "1" or "2" on the given object.
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
</sec:accesscontrollist>
```

c.f. http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/taglibs.html#d0e6991

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your approach

```
myobject.input.field1=ACL_READ
myobject.input.field2=ACL_READ,ACL_WRITE
```

does not contain any information about `SID`s (Security IDs) that are granted specified permissions. SID is any subject that can be granted permission. For instance, user of your application or group of users.
Who is granted that `ACL_READ` permission for `myobject.input.field1` object? I guess you forgot about it.

Secondly, holding such a proprties file would be simply implementing your own database system. You'd better use existing software for that.

If you don't want to use full-blown RDBMS like PostgreSQL or Oracle, you can use file based relational databases.

Existing and tested software:

- SQLite
- HSQLDB

Comment: Okay, you've right, ACL is not what I want. I would like a link between ROLES and "object" 
`myobject.input.field1=ROLE_READ`
`myobject.input.field2=ROLE_READ,ROLE_WRITE`
RDBMS seems to me very complicated to the simple use I want.